# How to stop a while loop when a file is not found that is using XMLHttpRequest()'s?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, xmlhttprequest

I want to loop through local files and grab the information from them. map1.txt map2.txt ...

However when a file does not exist the code does not stop. The rawFile.status returns 404 and the console says it is on the rawFile.send(null) line. It just keeps going through the loop never ending and giving the same error.

I want it to stop making requests once the file does not exist.

```
i = 0;
  while (i != -1) {
    (function(i) {
      var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
      rawFile.open("GET", "../maps/map" + [i] + ".txt", false);
      rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.status == 404) {
          break; //(or i = -1;)
        }
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
          if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
           //do stuff
          }
        }
      };
      rawFile.send(null);
    })(i);
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: This is async stuff. You need to make it into an async function, `await` every request, and stop the loop when a response isn't what you want

Comment: I feel like your while loop should be based on a variable that triggers to false when a file is no reachable instead of an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 2):

`onreadystatechange` will be called asynchronously. You need to wait for the request to be done before scheduling the next one.

#### Solution 1: Callbacks

You can handle this by giving your function a callback that it can call once the request is done (like nodejs does for all its asynchronous APIs).
Typically the callback will have the `function(error, result) {}` signature - the first being either an error object if the function encountered an error or null in case it didn't, and the second one being the result of the async action.

Example with callbacks:

```js
function getFile(i, cb) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", "../maps/map" + [i] + ".txt", false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.status == 404) {
      cb(new Error("It's dead Jim!"), null);
    }
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
        //do stuff
        cb(null, "RESULT");
      }
    }
  };
  rawFile.send(null);
}

function doUntilNotFound(i = 0) {
  getFile(i, (error, result) => {
    if(error) {
      // handle error
    } else {
      // do something with result
      doUntilNotFound(i + 1);
    }
  });
}

doUntilNotFound();
```

However callbacks can become quite ugly after a few nestings - often referred to as [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

#### Solution 2: Promises

The newer, more modern way of doing async things is [`async / await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) and [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which will make your code easier to understand:

```js
function getFile(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "../maps/map" + [i] + ".txt", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (rawFile.status == 404) {
        reject(new Error("File not found"));
      }
      if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
        if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
          //do stuff
          resolve("RESULT");
        }
      }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
  });
}

async function downloadFiles() {
  try {
    for(let i = 0;; i++) {
      let result = await getFile(i);
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // handle file not found here
  }
}

downloadFiles();
```

#### Solution 3: Using Promises + fetch

Also you cam use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of `XMLHttpRequest` if you're already working with Promises:

```js
async function downloadFiles() {
  try {
    for(let i = 0;; i++) {
      const req = await fetch("../maps/map" + [i] + ".txt");
      const reader = req.body.getReader();
      // TODO: Read Response body, do something with it
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // handle file not found here
  }
}

downloadFiles();
```

This will make your code even shorter & simpler :)

Comment: The modern way has a syntax error in the last two lines of getFile(i). It is expecting a ',' and a "Declaration or statement expected". Why is that?

Comment: @Ami sorry i messed up the curly brackets - it should work now :)

Answer (score 1):

I like Turtlefights answer, but am offering an async alternative instead of going recursive:

first, start by making the request into a promise-returning function

```
function getFile(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
      rawFile.open("GET", "../maps/map" + [i] + ".txt", false);
      rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        resolve(rawFile)
      };
      rawFile.send(null);
  })
}
```

then, in your main function (which should be labeled `async` so you can await stuff), you can await each one in the foreach and check the reponse status, and break if it 404s. Something like this:

```
async function checkFiles() {
  let i = 0;
  const responses = [];
  while (i != -1) {
    const response = await getFile(i);
    if (response.status == 404) break;
    responses.push(response);
    i++;
  }
  return responses;
}
```

You might want to set up your `getFile` function with timeout conditions as well

Comment: The `onreadystatechange` will be called multiple times by the implementation - you need to check the status of the request (`rawFile.readyState`) before calling resolve() otherwise your promise will be resolved too early. (only when `readyState` is 4 the request has fully completed)

Comment: @Turtlefight oh, well that's a very good reason to not bother using that api! How obnoxious. To anybody reading this: stick to `fetch` or `axios` if you don't enjoy headaches. (jquery ajax is alright too)